# Find latest file from a group of files

Tags: linux

I have a file test.dat which has multiple files inside like a1,a2,a3 b1,b2,b3 c1,c2,c3. I want to keep the latest version of a,b and c.
I have used `cat test.dat|sort -r|sed -ne ''1',$p'` but it gives me the latest of the a series, I wanted the latest from a,b and c series. Any suggestions please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm completely rewriting my answer based on the clarifications you made on the comments. Assuming a file input like the following one:

```
rul@helicon:~$ cat test.dat 
/home/user/a_4.0.2
/home/user/a_3.0.2
/home/user/a_1.0.1
/home/user/b_R2.1.1
/home/user/b_2.1.1
/home/user/b_1.2.1
/home/user/b_1.1.1
/home/user/c_R1.1.1
/home/user/c_5.1.1
/home/user/c_3.1.1
/home/user/c_2.1.1
/home/user/c_1.1.1
```

You can have the files you're looking for by doing:

```
rul@helicon:~$ for i in $(sort test.dat | cut -d_ -f1 | uniq); do grep -E ^$i test.dat | sort -r | head -n1; done
/home/user/a_4.0.2
/home/user/b_R2.1.1
/home/user/c_R1.1.1
```

A bit ugly, but it works.

Comment: Thanks rul, my contents inside the test.dat has the path aswell as shown below./home/user/a_4.0.2
/home/user/a_3.0.2
/home/user/a_1.0.1
/home/user/b_R2.1.1
/home/user/b_2.1.1
/home/user/b_1.2.1
/home/user/b_1.1.1
/home/user/c_R1.1.1
/home/user/c_5.1.1
/home/user/c_3.1.1
/home/user/c_2.1.1
/home/user/c_1.1.1

I want a_4.0.2,b_R2.1.1 and c_R1.1.1

Comment: All right, I misunderstood your question. Please provide expected real input and real output so I can fine tune my answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks again rul, i am not sure exactly what the code did but it works,actually my requirement was to output the rest of the files to test1.dat,meaning test1.dat should have all the versions of a,b,c except for the files /home/user/a_4.0.2
/home/user/b_R2.1.1
/home/user/c_R1.1.1  which are the latest ones. Please help.

Comment: INPUT---# cat cleanup.dat
/home/ar65172/mhublocal_5.0.2
/home/ar65172/artifactscommon_2.1.1
/home/ar65172/commonnzelt_2.1.1
/home/ar65172/artifactscommon_5.1.1
/home/ar65172/mhublocal_1.0.1
/home/ar65172/commonnzelt_1.2.1
/home/ar65172/artifactscommon_1.1.1
/home/ar65172/commonnzelt_1.1.1
/home/ar65172/commonnzelt_R2.1.1
/home/ar65172/artifactscommon_3.1.1
/home/ar65172/artifactscommon_R1.1.1
/home/ar65172/mhublocal_4.0.2
/home/ar65172/mhublocal_3.0.2

Comment: I need a file which should contain all these entries except /home/ar65172/mhublocal_5.0.2,/home/ar65172/artifactscommon_R1.1.1 &/home/ar65172/commonnzelt_R2.1.1  which are the latest versions

Comment: Try this: `for i in $(sort test.dat | cut -d_ -f1 | uniq); do grep -E ^$i test.dat | sort | head -n-1; done`, and please rate the answer if you think it's correct. ;-)

Comment: you are so awesome this nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cat test.dat | ls -t` the `-t` option will list the file by date in ascending order.

Comment: I guess it should be `cat file | xargs ls -t`